# wordpress plugin bbpress - login and registration form

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I have bbpress installed as a plugin in a wordpress site and want to display the Login form of forums but not display registration form. I am using below login form code

```
<?php 

      if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Forum')) : endif; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the 'Login Widget' included with bbPress in your sidebar?

http://codex.bbpress.org/widgets/